# Elasticsearch: Return only nested inner_hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
GET /networkcollection/branch_routers/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "queries",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": 
              { "queries.dateQuery": "20160101T200000.000Z" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

This returns both the "hits" object (the entire document), as well as the "inner_hits" object (nested inside of hits).

Is there a way to for me to only return the matched "queries" element(s) which appear in the "inner_hits" results, without getting the whole document?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Should be able to achieve it by disabling [source-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html)  at top-level by specifying  `"_source" : false`

```
POST /networkcollection/branch_routers/_search/
{
  "_source" : false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "queries",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": 
              { "queries.dateQuery": "20160101T200000.000Z" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! What a time saver!