# Disable hits and use exclusively inner_hits

Tags: elasticsearch

**>Beginner here.**

I have made a architecture for my profile - photo's application. In this application user can search for member by member's attributes and photo's attributes. And returned is only the photo's that have matched the query.

The problem is that one user might have thousands of photo's and each time a search is ran it return's hits: full object's of the profiles( with the nested photos ).

How can i make elasticsearch return only the value's of inner_hits?

Here is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "photo", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "photo.make": "BMW"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "photo.model": "111"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {"size": 1}
          }
        }
      ]
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of: [Elasticsearch: Return only nested inner_hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589084/elasticsearch-return-only-nested-inner-hits)

**Quoting:**
Should be able to achieve it by disabling source-field at top-level by specifying  "_source" : false

```
POST /networkcollection/branch_routers/_search/
{
  "_source" : false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "queries",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": 
              { "queries.dateQuery": "20160101T200000.000Z" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
  }
}
```